# Running harp.js on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, package.json, harp

I set up an Elastic Beanstalk instance on AWS based on node.js and I'm trying to get it to run harp.js.

It worked fine on Heroku with this Procfile:
`web: harp server --port $PORT`

But on AWS, there's not a Procfile (to my knowledge), so I changed the package.json file in the root to be the following:

```
   {
     "name": "Marketing-Website",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "My App",
     "dependencies": {
       "harp": "*"
     },
     "scripts": {
      "start": "harp server --port 80"
    }
   }
```

That doesn't seem to be working. In the server logs I end up with:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Marketing-Website package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     harp server --port 80
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs Marketing-Website
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Marketing-Website
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

> Marketing-Website@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> harp server --port 80

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1249:19)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at net.js:1408:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3


npm ERR! Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.12.2-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.12.2-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Marketing-Website@1.0.0 start: `harp server --port 80`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Marketing-Website@1.0.0 start script 'harp server --port 80'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Marketing-Website package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     harp server --port 80
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs Marketing-Website
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Marketing-Website
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

> Marketing-Website@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> harp server --port 80

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1249:19)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at net.js:1408:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

When I ran it without the `--port 80` the website built, but I got a 502 Bad Gateway error on the root website. I went to what I thought was the default port and that timed out on me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it with root access to use port 80

you can change the start script to:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "sudo harp server --port 80"
}
```